# Why does JText::_ not translate in model field?

Tags: language, debug

Not quite sure how to debug this.

We have a modal where labels are shown translated, but the options in the select input are not.

```
$options[] = JHtml::_('select.option', 'GB', JText::_('COM_COMPANY_LOCATION_GB'));
```

File location is components/com_company/models/fields/servers.php

The constant is defined in all language files.

I can see that the right language is loaded with `$lang->getName()`.

Adding `$lang->load('com_company');` does not fix it.

Any debugging tip would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried enabling language debug?

Comment: @Sharky Nop, lemme check that...

Comment: @Sharky Funny. It shows the correct translation then language debug is set to on. When I set it back to off, it again shows the faulty English strings.

Comment: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=960642 Some guy had the same problem, from 2018. No answer tho.